# Rails 4.2.3 Test my applications REST response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http

I m building an app which reacts to http requests.
So far it was ok to check the log file and the tables. I used curl to send the request like:

```
curl -u test -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/information -d ''
```

But now i included some kind of response mechanism. My question now is what port do i have to use for my responses? 
Is it  port 80 (std http port) ? And are there some CLI tools available which allow to handle a session?

Answer (score 0):

The port depends on your config and which arguments you use when starting the server. By default rails start on port 3000 - using port 80 will in most cases require the use of `sudo`. You can see the port in the output when starting the rails server.

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

There are several browser extensions such as [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) which provide a GUI for sending REST requests - in the way that is much easier than trying to piece it all together in a monster cURL invocation.

This is useful for debugging - but manually testing your applications is very error-prone and known to be an incomplete and flawed approach*. Instead, you should consider using automated tests.

Example of an [RSpec request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec):

```
# spec/requests/pets_api_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe "Pets API", type: :request do

  subject { response }
  let(:json) { JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_keys: true) }
  let(:pet) { Pet.create(name: 'Spot') }

  describe "viewing a Pet" do
    before { get pet_path(pet) }
    it { should have_http_status :ok }
    it "has the correct JSON response" do
      expect(json[:type]).to eq 'Pet'
      expect(json[:data][:name]).to eq 'Spot'
    end
  end

  describe "creating a Pet" do
    let(:valid_session) do
      # setup session here.
    end

    before do
      post "/pets", { type: 'Pet', data: { name: 'Doge' } }, valid_session
    end
    it { should have_http_status :created }
    # ... 
  end
end
```